# Could not include javascript file dynamically using angular4 and Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

I am unable to include one javascript file dynamically inside angular4 submit method. I am explaining my code below.

```
onTextFormSubmit(){
    this.processValidation = true;
    if (this.textForm.invalid) {
      return;
    } 
    let urlValue = this.textForm.value;
    let url = urlValue.url;
      console.log('hello',url);
      var script = document.createElement("SCRIPT");
      script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
      script.setAttribute("src", url);
      script.setAttribute('integrity', 'sha384-tEgmOghGBnPJQ3h63qzTE8V69SDVkIIyQeOFDfsG+AWJqA/UfZMmyQcXQVunl3wT');
      script.setAttribute('crossorigin','anonymous');
      document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
  }
```

Here the `url` parameter is coming from form submit which is like `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js` this and I am including it dynamically but after submit when I am doing `view page source` and searching that file isnide the `head` tag, I did not found there which is my issue. I need to include this file dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Iv'e tested it in my environment and it also failed.
Iv'e got the following error:

> Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for
>   resource 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js' with computed
>   SHA-256 integrity 'BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44='. The
>   resource has been blocked.

After a little search I found this [git issue](https://github.com/miguelcobain/ember-paper/issues/224) that resolved it.

Simply add the following attribute to your script:

```
 script.setAttribute('integrity','');
```

**Edit:**

If it's still doesn't work try this :

```
script.setAttribute('integrity','sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=');
script.setAttribute('crossorigin','anonymous');
```

Comment: I did but same issue.